# How to apply a function to multiple dataframe columns and create a corresponding number of columns programatically?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a function that takes in a dataframe and a list, and then creates n new columns (with different, programatically-generated names), and returns the expanded dataframe.

Say for instance that you have a dataframe consisting of three columns:

| Dogs | Cats | Horses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Bobby" | "Memphis" | "Incitatus" |
| "Rudolph" | "Django" | "Rocinante" |

*(in this case, the **type** of the data in the rows is not particularly important)*

Say that I wanted to apply a function such as follows (pseudocode) to the entire dataframe:

```py
def my_function(name, list_of_names):
   if name in list_of_names:
      perform operations
      return something
   else:
      perform operations
      return something_else
```

I want to apply the function to the entire dataframe so it creates three additional columns, called Dogs_new, Cats_new, Horses_new, but in a way that if a n number of columns were added to the original dataframe, a corresponding number of columns would be added (named as `f"{original name}_new"`).

The entire thing could be something resembling:

```py
def main_function(dataframe, list_of_names):
    # for every column in the dataframe
    colnames = list(dataframe)
    for col in colnames:
       new_name = f"{col}_new"
       dataframe[new_name] = dataframe.apply(lambda x: my_function(x."original colname", list_of_names), axis=1)

    return dataframe
```

However, using this approach, I cannot assign programatically the parameter with the name of the original column in the .apply function with the lambda, as I cannot use f expressions in function parameters. My whole approach seems a bit anti-pythonic too, and I feel that I am missing something or overthinking this.

The first approach would be to create them non-programatically, such as:

```py
df["Dogs_new"] = df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x.Dogs, list_of_names), axis=1)
df["Cats_new"] = df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x.Cats, list_of_names), axis=1)
df["Horses_new"] = df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x.Horses, list_of_names), axis=1)
```

Obviously, this is feasible for a low number of initial columns, but is not feasible at scale.

I've struggled with this problem and have tried a bunch of solutions using functions such as df.map, df.applymap, df.apply without a lambda, etc.

Comment: Hi. *I cannot assign programmatically the parameter with the name of the original column in the apply function with the lambda, as I cannot use f expressions in function parameters.* How so?

Comment: @laurent How would you go about it? Is it possible to do something to the effect of  `dataframe.apply(lambda x: my_function(x.f"original colname", list_of_names), axis=1)` , but with "original colname" changing according to the n-th colname? Or am I going really erratically about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it by using the dataframe [columns](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.columns.html) attribute and [indexing operators](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-and-selecting-data) `[]`:

```py
for col in df.columns:
    df[f"{col}_new"] = df.apply(lambda x: my_function(x[col], list_of_names), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Will check later if it works as intended and if so, will accept it!